# Need help programmatically setting a UIImageVIew Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I want to do is set the image of an empty UIImageView but whatever I try, nothing seems to work. Sorry if this is stupid, I am new to Xcode and Obj-C. The UIImageView takes up whole of the view, and there is a button to load the image (I have also tried putting this in the viewDidLoad bit, no success). Here is the code from my ViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)buttonChangeImage:(id)sender {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];
    [_imageView setImage:image];
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put a breakpoint and check that image is not nil and _imageView is not nil. If image is nil verify if 1.jpg is in the target. If _imageView is nil check the outlet connection.

Comment: Thanks it is working now (after a lot of trying!). imageView was nil and fixing it was as simple as redoing the outlet. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you did not connect IBOutlet _imageView with imageView in XIB or Storyboard.

Comment: It was as simple as a broken outlet connection, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you're having trouble interpreting @djromero's comment, here's how you could see if your problem is with the image:

```
- (IBAction)buttonChangeImage:(id)sender {
    UIImage * imageToAdd = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];
    if (imageToAdd) {
        _imageView.image = imageToAdd;
        NSLog(@"Image exists, if still not working, make sure _imageView is set properly");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"There was a problem loading your image, make sure it is named properly");
    }

    if (_imageView) {
        NSLog(@"ImageView exists!");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"ImageView does not exist, make sure it is properly connected");
    }
}
```

Comment: Except you're missing the crucial part: checking that `_imageView` is not `nil`.

Comment: @neilco - Updated to test that as well.